# Problems with cite package

Tags: natbib, elsarticle, cite-package

I am using `natbib` for managing references. But I wanted to get compressed or grouped references, so I switched to `cite` package. I deleted all the `.aux` files generated by latex and recompiled after changing the code. When `cite` package is used I'm getting an error message which looks like:

```
File ended while scanning use of \org@@citex.
<inserted text>
\par
```

And:

```
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
```

Which is the error you usually get if you have missed a `}` somewhere. But the same code compiles without the cite package, so it seems there is nothing actually wrong with it. Here is a MWE:

```
 \documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
This is a test document. \cite{Ghasemi-Mobarakeh2011,Zhao19994942,Robinson1985}
\end{document}
```

Code without package which doesn't give the error. But references appear as [1,2,3]

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
This is a test document. \cite{Ghasemi-Mobarakeh2011,Zhao19994942,Robinson1985}
\end{document}
```

Code with `cite` package which gives the error mentioned earlier.
I've checked that I'm using the latest version of `cite` package, I'm not able to find the source of the error.

Comment: The `elsarticle` class is specifically for publications with Elsevier journals. Unless they mandate it, I would not load `cite` or `natbib`: the class will likely do this for you _if_ it's allowed.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the clash is with the elsarticle class, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: if you want an `authoryear` reference style, then you should load it in the document class option. i.e. `\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}`

Answer (score 5):

The `elsarticle` class automatically loads `natbib`. As described in the class manual, options for `natbib` should then be set using `\biboptions`: you want `\biboptions{sort&compress}`.